# C-Media AC97 Audio Driver update?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, audio

I installed the C-Media AC97 Audio Driver from the CD which came with motherboard, but the Audio Driver is very old I think. Driver date: 2004.08.26. and driver version: 5.12.1.46. Isn't there any updates to this thing? Or maybe I can use some other Audio Driver which is more up-to-date which would turn out in better quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... The canonical site would be [C-Media's own site](http://www.cmedia.com.tw/EN/DownloadCenter_Detail2.aspx?pserno=0&dtype=ALL) but be forwarned: 1) You need to know the exact model of the sound chipset in your mainboard. 2) If your board is per chance an OEM one, you may be out of luck, because OEMs, particularly 1-tier ones, love to fiddle with the hardware IDs so that you can only use the drivers provided by them (talk about buyer lock in...).

Comment: How to find the model number of sound chipset on my motherboard?

Comment: I totally missed your question, sorry. In windows, you access the device manager and look the properties of your sound driver there. For example in Windows XP (what I have at hand at the moment), you open the start menu, right-click on "My Computer", select properties and in the resulting window select the "Hardware" tab. There you click on the "Device Manager" button and you'll find the list of all the install device drivers. The procedure in later versions of Windows is similar.